# House sparrow or something else?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

These little flying fellows seemed to have made themselves a small nest in the crevices of the roof of my house (I live in Poland). I don't know if this makes a difference, but I do live near a small park.

I'm wondering if this is a house sparrow or something else.

On one of the photos I could swear these look like common sparrows, but on another (the one where the wings are apart) it seems like a different species. It also seemed larger than a sparrow, but is hard to tell due to the distance at which I've seen the birds and the photos were taken. One other notable feature was that they seemed very loud...

Any help?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your image I would rather identify it as an [Eurasian Tree Sparrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurasian_tree_sparrow). They are pretty similar to the House Sparrow, but have a distinct black spot below their eyes which is missing for the House Sparrows (image from the Wikipedia):

[image]